# Laravel Model relationship "Page have many Attachments"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have models:

**Page**:

- id
- slug

**Image**

- id
- file

**Video**

- id
- file

I need the Page model to have a relation with several Image and Video models through one relationship, like

```
foreach($page->attachments as $attachment)
{
    // $attachment can be Image or Video
}
```

And inserts like

```
$attachments = [$image, $video];
$page->attachments()->saveMany($attachments);
```

I tried to make a morph relationship, but nothing comes of it, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Attachment Model and attachments Table with the following columns/properties:

- id
- file
- page_id
- type (video/image)

then you could add hasmany relationship to your page model

```
public function attachments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Attachment::class);
}
```

Then you can fetch the attachment like you tried

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this you have to make table for relations. This table should be defined like this:

**page_image_video**

- id
- page_id
- image_id
- video_id

And fields `page_id`, `image_id` and `video_id` should be a foreign keys. This is a table where you will save you attachments for your page. After that, you can define method `attachments()` in you Page Model with `hasMany()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Create Migration :**

**Page Table :**

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->increments('id');

    $table->string("slug");

    $table->timestamps();

});
```

**Image Table :**

```
Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->increments('id');

    $table->string("file");

    $table->timestamps();

});
```

**Videos Table :**

```
Schema::create('video', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->increments('id');

    $table->string("file");

    $table->timestamps();

});
```

**Pageables Table :**

```
Schema::create('pageables', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->integer("pages_id");

    $table->integer("pageable_id");

    $table->string("pageable_type");

});
```

**Create Model :**

Now, we will create Pages, Images and Video model. we will also use morphToMany() and morphedByMany() for relationship of both model.

**Video Model :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Video extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table='video';
    protected $primaryKey='id';

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function pages()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Pages::class, 'pageable');
    }
}
```

**Images Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Images extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table='image';
    protected $primaryKey='id';

    protected $guarded = [];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function pages()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Pages::class, 'pageable');
    }
}
```

**Pages Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;


class Pages extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table='page';
    protected $primaryKey='id';

    protected $guarded = [];
    public $timestamps = false;


    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Images::class, 'pageable');
    }

    /**
     * Get all of the videos that are assigned this tag.
     */
    public function videos()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Video::class, 'pageable');
    }


}
```

**Retrieve Records :**

```
$pages = Pages::find(1);
        foreach ($pages->posts as $post) {
            var_dump($post);
        }
        foreach ($pages->videos as $video) {
            print_r('<br>');
            //var_dump($video);
        }
```

**Create Records :**

$page = Pages::find(1);

```
    $img = new Images();
    $img->file = "test insert";

    $page->posts()->save($img);
```

***All done.***